# Windows Server 2012 - Grant rights to view folder content

Tags: php, webserver, windows-server-2012-r2

I have built a client and data management software for a company (PHP) and now I'd like to make folders accessible.

To clarify my need let me put up an example:

If a clients documents are being viewed my PHP script reads everything that lies in `XXX/CLIENT_ID/FOLDERNAME/` and puts it out to the view.

Now my client has announced the wish to upload whole folders into clients in order to import old data.

Therefore the new request would look like `XXX/CLIENT_ID/FOLDERNAME/NEW_FOLDER/`

I would like to drop out a quick for them to view the folders content.
As far as I remember, if you try to request an URL which is a folder and has no index.html / php file it should display the contents, whether its more folders or some other documents, shouldnt it ?

Unfortunately when I try to access that extra folder I receive a 403 Error Forbidden.

Comment: Why not test the theory? Create a folder and see if it does so?

Comment: Hehe, sorry if I didn't make myself clear. Of course I did and testet it - > I have received a 403 Forbidden Error though.

Comment: It might be a obvious question but none the less: You have set the right permissions for the webuser to the folder?

Comment: @Epodax When I rightclick the folder and check the permissions my and any other user has full permissions.